# Bulk Download Images with Organization

Tags: download, batch-file, sftp

I have a list of URLs (pretty much all image urls though some pdf) that I need downloaded. I have found a variety of options for bulk downloading and these would work but I need them to be organized by the directory they are listed as in the URL. For Example:

```
samplesite.com/sample1/image1.jpg
samplesite.com/sample1/image2.jpg
samplesite.com/sample1/image3.jpg
samplesite.com/sample2/image1.jpg
samplesite.com/sample2/image2.jpg
samplesite.com/sample2/image3.jpg
```

I would need to be organized like this:

> **Folder Sample1**
>    image1.jpg
>    image2.jpg
>    image3.jpg
>   **Folder Sample2**
>    image1.jpg
>    image2.jpg
>    image3.jpg

I do have SFTP access but each directory is terribly organized and has image files mixed with other irrelevant files. Additionally, most of the batch scripts I have tried to create have had issues. When I did `xCopy` there was no way to figure out which files failed, and when I did `robocopy` speed was compromised. Any suggestions on how I should go about moving forward? Existing software is preferred, but I am fine with advice on how I should script this. I prefer not to have to install anything to access SFTP via command line, but if that's the only option, it is what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `wget` can do that with some options. Please try `wget -input-file=urls.txt --force-directories`

From the [wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html):

> --input-file=file
>   Read URLs from a local or external file. If ‘-’ is specified as file, URLs are read from the standard input. (Use ‘./-’ to read from a file literally named ‘-’.)

and

> --force-directories
>   The opposite of ‘-nd’—create a hierarchy of directories, even if one would not have been created otherwise. E.g. ‘wget -x http://fly.srk.fer.hr/robots.txt’ will save the downloaded file to fly.srk.fer.hr/robots.txt.

Comment: Worked like a charm for URLs. Do you happen to know if it supports SFTP?

Comment: I think in that case you need to switch to curl instead of wget.