# Bulk SFTP download of files specified by URL preserving directories

Tags: batch, download, wget, sftp, curl

I have a list of several hundred files I need to pull via SFTP. They are located in various directories and I need them to be in the same directory setup on my local machine. It is important the files on the list located in these directories are not included in the download.

I asked this question for downloading URLs here: [Bulk Download Images with Organization](https://superuser.com/questions/884482/). I need to have the option of SFTP download available to me as well. Any recommendations on going about doing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any software that can do it our of the box.

I even suppose you won't find any, as using an HTTP URL as SFTP download specification is not common and there's not even any direct mapping from the URL to an SFTP path.

If you have a URL like

```
https://www.example.com/sample1/image1.jpg
```

The file as presented using the SFTP will be in `/sample1/usage1.jpg` only if the website SFTP account is chrooted. If not, the file can be in path like `/home/user/httpdocs/sample1/usage1.jpg` or any other.

So I believe you have to script it somehow.

Also you didn't specify if the hostname in the URL changes or is constant. If it changes, where do you get the host credentials from? Or are they included in the URLs too?

Below, see an example of PowerShell script using [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library).

Configure the `$remoteRoot` accordingly.

```
try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
    Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
    $sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    $sessionOptions.HostName = "example.com"
    $sessionOptions.UserName = "user"
    $sessionOptions.Password = "mypassword"
    $sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...="

    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

    $remoteRoot = "/home/user"

    try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("list.txt"))
        {
            if ($line -Match "http\://[a-z.]+(/(.*)/[a-z0-9.]+)$")
            {
                $remotePath = $matches[1]
                $remoteDir = $matches[2]
                $localDir = $remoteDir -Replace "/", "\"

                if (!(Test-Path $localDir))
                {
                    Write-Host "Creating directory $localDir"
                    New-Item $localDir -Type directory | Out-Null
                }

                Write-Host "Downloading $remotePath"
                $session.GetFiles(($remoteRoot + $remotePath), ($localDir + "\")).Check()
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "$line does not have expected URL format"
            }
        }        
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }

    exit 0
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    exit 1
}
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: I believe the questioner is referring to a `sftp://` url and not a `http://` url.  I'm kind of amazed that there is no software that can do this out of the box.  I bet if an sftp client were to add this to their feature list, it would make the author cool and popular.

Comment: @cowlinator It would be quite inefficient to mass download files using SFTP URL. Using an URL as a download specification kind of implies a new connection for every file. SFTP/SSH connection is *expensive* to be opened for each file separately. SFTP/SSH is designed to be opened continuously, not per-request (as HTTP). That's why URL is rarely used for SFTP. There's even no standard for SFTP URL syntax.

Comment: Whether or not a new connection is created for every file is up to the implementation of the client if the input is in the form of a list of URLs.  I'm surprised there is no standard for SFTP URLs, this protocol has been around for decades...

Comment: In lack of an official standard, this RFC draft seems to be the closest thing to a standard that we have.  https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04#section-4  And I think this is what most people would use if they created an SFTP URL.

Comment: Anyway, you may consider asking a new question that is explicitly about SFTP URLs.